# How can I locate key without knowing the previous level info in JSON file

Tags: python, json

I am using Python to open a JSON file, and what I have so far is the Champion key, what I want to get is the Champion name. How can I do that because I don't know the key 266 is corresponding to the Champion name 'Aatrox'?

Python Code:

```
key = 266
with open('C:/Users/robin/Documents/Riot project/champion.json', 'rb') as f:
    champion_info = json.load(f)
if champion_info['data'][**what should I write here?**]['id'] == key:
    champion_name = ...
```

JSON file:

```
{
"type": "champion",
"format": "standAloneComplex",
"version": "10.16.1",
"data": {
    "Aatrox": {
        "version": "10.16.1",
        "id": "Aatrox",
        "key": "266",
        "name": "Aatrox",
        "title": "the Darkin Blade"
```

}

Comment: Is there only Aatrox that is unknown or can their be more then one level to go down to find the key?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is this.

```
champion_info = {
    "type": "champion",
    "format": "standAloneComplex",
    "version": "10.16.1",
    "data": {
        "Aatrox": {
            "version": "10.16.1",
            "id": "Aatrox",
            "key": "266",
            "name": "Aatrox",
            "title": "the Darkin Blade"
        }
    }
}


target_key = "266"
detail = list(champion_info["data"].values())[0]
if detail["key"] == target_key:
    champion_name = detail["id"]
```

If you need the query frequently, it would be nice to make a key-id map.

It assumes you have all champ's info list like below:

champ_info_li = [champion_info_01, champion_info_02, ...]

```
key_id_map = dict()

for champion_info in champ_info_li:
    detail = list(champion_info["data"].values())[0]
    key = detail["key"]
    id = detail["id"]
    key_id_map[key] = id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the keys:

```
dct = {
    "type": "champion",
    "format": "standAloneComplex",
    "version": "10.16.1",
    "data": {
        "Aatrox": {
            "version": "10.16.1",
            "id": "Aatrox",
            "key": "266",
            "name": "Aatrox",
            "title": "the Darkin Blade"

        }
    }
}

needle = "Aatrox"
for key in dct['data']:
    if dct['data'][key]['id'] == needle:
        print("Yippie")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
champion_info = { 
    "type": "champion", 
    "format": "standAloneComplex", 
    "version": "10.16.1", 
    "data": 
        { "Aatrox": { "version": "10.16.1", "id": "Aatrox", "key": "266", "name": "Aatrox", "title": "the Darkin Blade"
}}}

key = "266"

res = [{k: champion_info["data"].get(k)} for k in champion_info["data"].keys() if champion_info["data"].get(k).get("key") == key]

print(res)
```